# What is the difference between these thread pools in Websphere?

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere, threadpool, websphere-6.1

In WebSphere Application Server, I see two thread pools that I can manipulate. There is one called "default", and another called "WebContainer", each having a minimum and maximum size.

What is each of these thread pools used for? In my application, I am using Java's ExecutorService to push off work on to separate threads--which of these pools would I be pulling from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "default" thread pool is really only used during server startup.  The "WebContainer" thread pool is used for inbound HTTP requests.

The WebSphere Application Server thread pools have no integration with ExecutorService, so you won't be using any of these.  Which ExecutorService are you using?  If you're using one from Executors, then that will create its own threads.

Comment: I've mostly been using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)), and wrapping with Guava's [ListeningDecorator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html)

Comment: I guess I got confused and thought that Java was pulling from the WebSphere thread pool